# Creating objects from array of objects in a grouped mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have been writing an aggregation pipeline to show a summarized version of data from a collection.

Sample Structure of Document:

```
{
    _id: 'abcxyz',
    eventCode: 'EVENTCODE01',
    eventName: 'SOMEEVENT',
    units: 1,
    rate: 2,
    cost: 2,
    distribution: [
        {
            startDate: 2021-05-31T04:00:00.000+00:00
            units: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I have grouped it and merged the distribution into a single list with `$unwind` step before `$group`:

```
[
    $unwind: {
        path: '$distribution',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
    },
    $group: {
        _id: {
            eventName: '$eventName',
            eventCode: '$eventCode'
        },
        totalUnits: {
            $sum: '$units'
        },
        distributionList: {
            $push: '$distribution'
        },
        perUnitRate: {
            $avg: '$rate'
        },
        perUnitCost: {
            $avg: '$cost'
        }
    }
]
```

Sample Output:

```
{
    _id: {
        eventName: 'EVENTNAME101'
        eventCode: 'QQQ'
    },
    totalUnits: 7,
    perUnitRate: 2,
    perUnitCost: 2,
    distributionList: [
        {
            startDate: 2021-05-31T04:00:00.000+00:00,
            units: 1
        },
        {
            startDate: 2021-05-31T04:00:00.000+00:00,
            units: 1
        },
        {
            startDate: 2021-06-07T04:00:00.000+00:00,
            units: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting stuck at the next step; I want to consolidate the `distributionList` into a new List with no repeating `startDate`.

Example: Since first 2 objects of distributionList have the same startDate, it should be a single object in output with sum of units:

Expected:

```
{
    _id: {
        eventName: 'EVENTNAME101'
        eventCode: 'QQQ'
    },
    totalUnits: 7,
    perUnitRate: 2,
    perUnitCost: 2,
    newDistributionList: [
        {
            startDate: 2021-05-31T04:00:00.000+00:00,
            units: 2 //units summed for first 2 objects
        },
        {
            startDate: 2021-06-07T04:00:00.000+00:00,
            units: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I couldn't use `$unwind` or `$bucket` as I intend to keep the grouping I did in previous steps (`$group`).

Can I get suggestions or a different approach if this doesn't seem accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do the first `$group` at `eventName, eventCode, distribution.startDate` level. Then, you can `$group` again at `eventName, eventCode` level and using `$first` to keep your original `$group` fields.

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-_uP_94-R4-) to show the idea for your reference.